# Reinstall Numbers?

Tags: iwork, numbers

I got myself into a state where App Store says that I have numbers "installed" but in fact I don't have it installed. I tried the recommended option/click and shift/click over the installed button and it didn't work. Can you give me a tip?

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting the Mac App Store.

1. Enable the debug menu and restart the Mac App Store.

   ```
   defaults write com.apple.appstore ShowDebugMenu -bool true
   ```
2. Choose the **Reset Application** option.

   [image: App Store Debug Menu]

Comment: Sounded promising... but didn't seem to help. It still says "installed". How does it decide that it's installed? Because I can't find a numbers.app file or directory...